# Previous sprints shown when creating new board

Tags: jira, jira-agile

When I'm creating a new scrum-board for my project all the previous sprints are shown?

How can I make JIRA-Agile to start with a set of new sprints(sprint 1).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't configure your created scrum board.
go to your created scrum board and navigate to configure..then you can edit the filter for your scrum board.reason is you getting previous sprints in the board is you have used a previously used filter for your scrum board.so add a needed(unique) filter for the scrum board.
follow [this documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Scrum+Board) for more information